# Can I get a replacement credit card to overseas if I didn't activate the credit card account?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

I'm overseas.

I apply for a new credit card. I already have one credit card from this bank.

My address is the address on file. US residential. There's no one there right now.

They mail the card.

I then request for replacement to my overseas address.

PS. Bank doesn't send new cards to PO box or overseas. Hence this trick.

If this is ok, how do I know if the new card is approved and mailed so I can ask for a replacement?

Comment: when the first card goes to the US address what will happen to it. Will it get returned to the credit card company? will it sit at the post office? Will it be undelivered? That could impact your ability to get a replacement card.

Comment: It will appear delivered and just sit there. How could it impact?

Comment: If the post office sends it back and said you don't live there they might cancel the card and assume an attempt at fraud.

Comment: oh okay. so when should i order the replacement?

Comment: i don't remember if online banking shows the new card after its approved and before its activated

Comment: I think the only way to find out is to contact your bank and ask them.

Comment: I could be wrong but I wouldn't expect this to work. Banks will have seen this before, and if they won't mail a card overseas they probably won't mail a replacement overseas. At least they are going to make some checks. Like "how long have you been in the place you are asking the card to be sent?" By far the easiest way to fix this is to get someone to go to your house in the US and mail the card to you.

Answer (score -1):

In all cases when I have received a new card (or a replacement for a card that has expired, account number is still the same), the card has come with a peel-off sticker that says something like "Call 1 800 CAPITAL to activate your card" (and the phone call must be made from the phone number that the credit card company has on file, or was on the application form submitted for a new card). It is also possible to go to the website (if application for the card was submitted online as this one likely was), and verify to the  credit card company that the card is actually in the recipient's hands. So, how does this avoid someone stealing the card from the mailbox at the end of the driveway and activating it?  Well, first, the card is sent in an envelope that is not festooned with the credit card company logo or have any other markings indicating that it contains a credit card. Second, the phone call must come from the phone that the company knows about (which is either inside the house or in the OP's possession), and if the Internet is used for activation, the thief must also have the login credentials for the card website. You didn't reveal those to a sugar daddy, did you?